# Gnuplot: Undifined value during function evaluation

Tags: plot, gnuplot, exponential

i need to fit some data with sum of exponantial functions, but this shows all the time. Any suggestions how to do the fit?[image: this is what it says after trying to fit the data]

[image: This is my datafile]

Comment: Use proper initial values for your fitting parameters. If you don't set values, they default all to 1 which might be way outside the convergence range. And please don't post screenshots of your code and the data but include them as text in your question.

Comment: ok, I will try, and thanks for you advice about screenshots.

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needed to guess the initial value of variables really close to the result of the fit.

Thanks for your answer.